# Docker 'WARNING: permission denied' on ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

My ubuntu machine has suddenly started showing this warning when using docker:

```
WARNING: open /home/parallels/.dockercfg: permission denied
```

My current user is in the docker group and this was working fine. How do I fix this without just using sudo all the time?

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/home/parallels/.dockercfg` file?

Comment: Hmm, there doesn't seem to be a .dockercfg (I'm a linux n00b so apologies)

Comment: Found it: -rw------- 1 root root 73 Jan 16 20:47 .dockercfg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run a command with `sudo`, unless configured otherwise through the command-line options, you will be running as the system's `root` user. In your case, the file permissions are set as such that only the `root` user has read and write access to the file, forcing you to use `sudo` despite your user belonging to the `docker` group.

Try copying, pasting and running the following to remedy access to the file:

```
# Change working directory
cd /home/parallels && \
# Give the root user and those belonging to the `docker` group read/write access;
# revoke all permissions for everyone else
sudo chmod u=rw,g=rw,o= .dockercfg && \
# Set the ownership of the file to the `root` user and `docker` group
sudo chown root:docker .dockercfg
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you. However - do you know how/why this file would suddenly get in this state?

Comment: That's a very good question and seems to bring us to the root of the problem. I'll have to update my answer